# Looping over an array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In the facebook game I am making I have finally got this:

```
$app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
));

print_r($app_using_friends);
```

to get me this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [uid] => 1609874007 [name] => Anne Abrams Nadel-Walbridge ) [1] => Array ( [uid] => 100000024696650 [name] => Abbye Dively ) [2] => Array ( [uid] => 100004264273000 [name] => Nelson Sheridan Crowe ) )
```

I have played for hours and can't seem to get something written to each record to display in a loop using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this array like this:

```
foreach ($app_using_friends as $row) {
    echo $row['uid'] . ' ' . $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: oh, also yay 100th answer on this site :P